# Sqoop Export Hive String to Oracle CLOB

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I want to export **STRING** data from Hive to **CLOB** in Oracle.

Command :

`sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.41.67:1521:orcl' --username ILABUSER  --password  impetus --table ILABUSER.CDT_ORC_1  --export-dir /user/dev/db/123 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' -m 2`

Exception:

> Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not buffer record
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef
>       at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.lib.LobRef.clone(LobRef.java:109)
>       at ILABUSER_CDT_ORC_1.clone(ILABUSER_CDT_ORC_1.java:322)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:213)
>       ... 15 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I used `--map-column-java` tag.

I mapped **Clob column *(named col_clob)* to String in Java.**

Added below code in above command:

`--map-column-java tag col_clob=String`